# How does the inclusion of vacuum energy modify Newtonian gravity equation of motion?

Tags: gravity, cosmology, astrophysics, dark-energy

The equation of motion (in the center of mass frame) due only to gravitational forces between two point masses is:

$$\frac{d^2r}{dt^2} = -\frac{GM}{r^2}$$

How does the equation get modified when a repulsive force due to vacuum energy/dark energy is included?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We want the Newtonian limit of the Einstein Field equations for nonzero vacuum energy(=cosmological constant). As $\rho_\mathrm{vac}=\Lambda/4\pi G$ is a  mass(=energy) density, Poisson equation is
$$
\Delta\Phi=4\pi G\rho(\boldsymbol r)-\Lambda \tag{1}
$$

If we assume spherical symmetry, and point-like source $\rho\sim\delta(\boldsymbol r)$, the grativational potential that solves $(1)$ is
$$
\Phi(r)=-\frac{GM}{r}-\frac{1}{6}\Lambda r^2\tag{2}
$$
so that the gravitational acceleration is given by
$$
g=-\partial_r\Phi=-\frac{GM}{r^2}+\frac{1}{3}\Lambda r\tag{3}
$$

Comment: It is not F for the force but a for the acceleration, but the rest should be correct.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this. When finding the cosmological constant's contribution, what makes the point $r=0$ special? The equation $\nabla^2 \phi = \Lambda$ is inconsistent with the usual boundary condition that the potential goes to zero at infinity.

Comment: @Javier I've actually half written an answer to that effect. It's tricky, though, because in fact no experiment, neither local nor global, could locate $r = 0$, since with this particular potential the acceleration pushing any two points apart is exactly proportional to their separation. That is, Newton+metric expansion is self-consistent, it's just the more subtle issue of Newton+nonzero homogeneous gravity source that falls apart on consistency.

Comment: @javier im on my phone now. When i get home ill edit my answer to include more detail. But for now, nothing makes $r=0$ special but the fact that *I choose* to put a point mass there, that is, i took $\rho\propto\delta(r)$. And yes, poisson eq with a source such that $\rho\not\to 0$ is pathological, but in principle the solution "makes sense" physically speaking, because there is no reason for $g\to\eta$ (that is, $\Phi\to0$) if there is "mass everywhere" (constant vacuum energy). It similar to the divergent electric field of an infinite capacitor.

Comment: r=0 does not need to be special. It simply is the place where the mass is. This also works in n-body simulations where you have a bunch of r=0 all over the place, they don't need to be at the center of your coordinate system for this to work.

Comment: Taking $\Lambda = 10^{-29} \, \mathrm{g cm}^{-3}$, this means that the cosmological term would match the acceleration from our Sun at a distance of $r \approx 8.4\times 10^{20} \, \mathrm{cm} \approx 270 \, \mathrm{pc}$.  For the entire milky way, the distance would be about $r \approx 3 \, \mathrm{Mpc}$.

Answer (score 4):

You get an extra term that increases with r:

$$a = -\frac{G\cdot M}{r^2} + j\cdot r$$

with j as the repulsive component.

Comment: great minds think alike, right? :-)

Comment: I was 1 minute faster, but your answear has more details [: